# SQL Command to select from two tables at the same time

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

i have two tables "Companies" and "matches" . This is an example of a row from "companies" table :

```
{"id":11,"source_id":684,"source_name":"dataset_A.csv","name":"LES ATELIERS","website":"","email":"","phone":"01 43 43 17 48","address":"","postal_code":"75012.0","city":"","country":"France"}
```

This is an example of a row from "matches" table :

```
[{"id":6,"left_company_id":6322,"right_company_id":12319}]}
```

I want to make an SQL command that selects from matches where "right_company_id" equals a given id as a parameter, then after selecting the match I have to select from the "companies" table the company that has the 'id' the same as the left_company_id from the selected row of the "matches" table

Comment: i am using sqlite with nodeJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query can look like this for example:

```
select * from companies 
where id in ( select left_company_id from matches where right_company_id = 3)
```